# Button Border .kv in .py Kivy&Python

Tags: python, kivy

Есть кнопка с border по бокам кнопки.
Но проблема в том, что я знаю как сделать в .kv файле такую кнопку, а вот как такую же сделать только в .py файле, я не знаю.
Кнопка:

```
Button:
    text: 'test'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
        Line:
            width: 2
            rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
```

Comment: А чем kv не подходит?

Comment: В данный момент, мне нужно сделать это через python код.

Answer (score 1):

Что-то вроде этого, хотя можно лучше, мне кажется.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.graphics import Line, Color
from kivy.clock import Clock


class MyButton(Button):
    def __init__(self,**kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        self.text = 'test'
        Clock.schedule_once(self.update_border,1)

    def update_border(self,dt):
        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(rgba = (1,1,1,1))
            Line(width = 2,rectangle = (self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height))

class Main(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        self.add_widget(Widget())
        self.add_widget(MyButton())
        self.add_widget(Widget())


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```